# CSS (selector) not working on a WAMP server (W10)

Tags: html, css, localhost, wamp

I was a lot of time busy, with learning HTML, and i decided to make wamp server. Everything whent OK and i started to code the HTML. But when i started to code te CSS the selector will not show in the webpage on my local domain(rolfweb.net:8080). But in localhost it shows all CSS correctly!
Code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> RolfWeb </title>

</head>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/indexss.css"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li> Home </li>
            <li> Video's </li>
            <li> Games </li>
            <li> Contact en informatie </li>
            <li> Over mij </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p> Test </p>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
p {
    color: blue;
}
/* This is not working! */
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #3f875f;
    border: 3px solid #3a756c;
    text-align: center;
}
```

So it shows good on localhost but on rolfweb.net:8080 not.

PS: Sorry for my bad english i'm dutch :P

Comment: Can you confirm if there is any folder structure? ie localhost = www/ & rolfweb.net = www/rolfweb/

Comment: @Nick_O localhost = www/ and RolfWeb = www/ Thats where i put all html files. I found out that the standard browser (IE.exe) have access to rolfweb.net:8080 and localhost:8080. But my other browsers only have access to localhost:8080.

Comment: How can that be? Have set up a local domain via your host file & apache etc? If so all browsers should work.

Comment: Wait a second i gonna check my files.

Answer (score 2):

Move your css link within the head tags:-

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> RolfWeb </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/indexss.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li> Home </li>
        <li> Video's </li>
        <li> Games </li>
        <li> Contact en informatie </li>
        <li> Over mij </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p> Test </p>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Not worked. I had it in the head tags but i thought that it was wrong so i put it in the body tags but nothing happened. );

Comment: Check your developers console for errors. Right click on the page & select inspect element.

Comment: I can't find anything